# How to Display blocking message box using inno setup pascal scripting

Tags: inno-setup, mutex, pascal, messagebox

I'm creating installer for my application using inno setup (pascal script),in my setup there is a requirement that if user runs the setup twice a message has to be displayed saying that "another instance is already running" by checking the mutex, i have impletemented that now the problem is it displays the message box but if user still try's to run the setup again and again the above message willbe displayed multiple times which i don't want.so my message box should block him doing anything on his machine untill the messagebox is closed.

EDIT: I wanted to block the current window from where the user is running the setup, to prevent the user from running the setup from same location again.

my sample code:

```
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program

[Code]
const
  MB_APPLMODAL =   $00002000;
  MB_SYSTEMMODAL = $00001000;
  MB_ICONHAND = $00000010;
  MB_ICONQUESTION = $00000020;
  MB_ICONEXCLAMATION = $00000030;
  MB_ICONASTERISK = $00000040;
  MB_ICONSTOP = MB_ICONHAND;
  MB_ICONINFORMATION = MB_ICONASTERISK;

#ifdef UNICODE
  #define AW "W"
#else
  #define AW "A"
#endif

function MessageBox(hWnd: HWND; lpText, lpCaption: string;
  uType: UINT): Integer; external 'MessageBox{#AW}@user32.dll stdcall';

function SysModalMsgBox(Owner: HWND; const Text: string; MsgType: TMsgBoxType;
  Buttons: Integer): Integer;
var
  Flags: UINT;
  Caption: string;
begin
  Flags := Buttons;

  case MsgType of
    mbInformation: Flags := Flags or MB_ICONINFORMATION;
    mbConfirmation: Flags := Flags or MB_ICONQUESTION;
    mbError: Flags := Flags or MB_ICONEXCLAMATION;
    mbCriticalError: Flags := Flags or MB_ICONSTOP;
  end;

  if not IsUninstaller then
    Caption := SetupMessage(msgSetupAppTitle)
  else
    Caption := SetupMessage(msgUninstallAppTitle);  

  Result := MessageBox(Owner, Text, Caption, MB_SYSTEMMODAL);
end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  Sleep(5000);
  SysModalMsgBox(WizardForm.Handle, 'Another instance is runinng please try again!',mbInformation , MB_OK);

end;
```

Comment: I would immediately delete such installer. No application should ever try to block the whole system, no matter if it's installer. FYI, Martijn added a directive to allow running only one setup at a time.

Comment: blocking the system  meant "it should not allow the user to run the setup again"

Comment: You would have to prevent the user from running the setup binary, and that is a system block. You can make some sort of instance counting, which when reaches 2 will just exit the setup without displaying that message box. But I don't get why do you care about this at all. Are you expecting your users being total idiots :) ? If so, you should ideally prevent them installing anything but your application because I doubt that someone has ever dealt with such *issue*.

Comment: as of now i'm trying to get the messagebox handle (using its caption) , if its found then i'm quitting from setup, is it a good practice ? because still for every click it launches the exe and quits.